# EF4.1 LINQ, selecting all results

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to LINQ queries and to EF too, I usually work with MySQL and I can't guess how to write really simples queries.

I'd like to select all results from a table. So, I used like this:

```
ZXContainer db = new ZXContainer();
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties.All();
```

But I see that I have to write something inside All(---).

Could someone guide me in how could I do that? And if someone has any good link for references too, I thank so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`All()` is an boolean evaluation performed on all of the elements in a collection (though immediately returns false when it reaches an element where the evaluation is false), for example, you want to make sure that all of said ZXproperties have a certain field set as true:

```
bool isTrue = db.ZXproperties.All(z => z.SomeFieldName == true);
```

Which will either make `isTrue` true or false. LINQ is typically lazy-loading, so if you're calling `db.ZXproperties` directly, you have access to all of the objects as is, but it isn't quite what you're looking for. You can either load all of the objects at the variable assignment with an `.ToList()`:

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties.ToList();
```

or you can use the below expression:

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = from s in db.ZXproperties
                       select s;
```

Which is really no different than saying:

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties;
```

The advantage of `.ToList()` is that if you are wanting to do multiple calls on this ViewBag.ZXproperties, it will only require the initial database call when it is assigning the variable. Alternatively, if you do any form of queryable action on the data, such as `.Where()`, you'll have another query performed, which is less than ideal if you already have the data to work with.

Answer (score 1):

To select everything, just skip the `.All(...)`, as ZXproperties allready is a collection.

```
ZXContainer db = new ZXContainer();
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties;
```

You might want (or sometimes even need) to call `.ToList()` on this collection before use...

Answer (score 0):

You don't use All. Just type

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties;
```

or

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var result = db.ZXproperties.ToList();
```

For more information on linq see [`101 linq sample`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746/).

All is some checking on all items and argument in it, called [`lambda expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: downvoter you should explain why downvoting, as I see you downvoted my answer and Reed Copsey ones, both of answers are correct, it's not a good way to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

The [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534754%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method is used to determine if all items of collection match some condition.

If you just want all of the items, you can just use it directly:

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties;
```

If you want this evaluated immediately, you can convert it to a list:

```
ViewBag.ZXproperties = db.ZXproperties.ToList();
```

This will force it to be pulled across the wire immediately.